# 'ruby-dbus' in TTY terminal

Tags: ruby, rubygems, dbus, tty

i have the next code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
require 'dbus'
bus = DBus::SessionBus.instance
```

If i execute this code from desktop, it's fine. But if i execute the code in a TTY1-6 terminal i get this output:

> home/migue/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ruby-dbus-0.11.0/lib/dbus/bus.rb:611:in 
>   'address_from_file': undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
>
> from /home/migue/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/ruby-dbus-0.11.0/lib/dbus/bus.rb:600:in 'initialize'
>
> from /home/migue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/singleton.rb:141:in 'new'
>
> from /home/migue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/singleton.rb:141:in 'block in instance'
>
> from /home/migue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/singleton.rb:139:in 'synchronize'
>
> from /home/migue/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/singleton.rb:139:in 'instance'
>
> from bus.rb:3:in '< main >'

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/mvidner/ruby-dbus/blob/v0.11.0/lib/dbus/bus.rb#L611) reveals this line:

```
display = ENV["DISPLAY"][/:(\d+)\.?/, 1]
```

The `NoMethodError` occurs, because `ENV["DISPLAY"]` returns `nil`.

Setting the [DISPLAY environment variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable) in your terminal should fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem.

Comment: @Madh I've opened a [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mvidner/ruby-dbus/issues/53)